# Who does the arithmetic and logic operations in the Java or C++ source code?

Tags: java, c++

Eg:

```
int a = 6;
int b = 5;
int c = a + b; // Who does this?
```

Does the compiler do it?

**If so, how about a program that takes those values of a and b from the console input?** In that case, the object / exe file is already created and the compiler only works on source files, right?

Comment: This is probably executed by the (micro) processor.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the compiler emits instructions for the processor to perform.

However, the compiler may optimize constants and emit other instructions.  In the case above, the compiler may emit the instructions:

```
  mov C, 11  ; Move the value 11 into register for the C variable.
```

With Java, the compiler creates Java Byte Codes for the Java Virtual machine to execute.  Again, the instructions may be simplified or optimized by the compiler or by the JVM.

**Edit 1: Reading from Console**
In C++, the compiler emits instructions, for the statements you gave it, to read in values from the console.  If you don't have statements in your program to read from the console, the compiler won't emit any instructions for reading from the compiler.

In Java, similar to C++, but Java Byte Codes are emitted and executed by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Comment: Ok, in case of console input, I guess it emits the instructions before producing the byte code and then what?  Does it emit again when the console input is provided? Or Does the compiler edit the byte code after the console input is provided or does the JVM do it? Or no editing takes place.

Comment: I think you should read up on system architecture. Stackoverflow is not the place to teach you the very basics of code execution.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a *compiler* and an *interpreter*.  With a compiler, the processor instructions are emitted once to an executable file.  I recommend writing a "Hello world" program, compiling it and looking at the assembly language.  The "truth" is in the assembly language.

Comment: How do I look at the assembly code of a Java compiled program?

Comment: @MofX: These details were never taught in our programming class and I was curious. I could read up SA but it would be greek and latin.

Answer (score 1):

In the concrete example you introduce, any minimally smart compiler (read: all of them) will know that the result is a constant. So, `c` will be given the exact value of 11.

In the case of these variables being read from the console, the compiler cannot make any assumption of the values, so it will generate the processor instructions needed to get any value that those variables hold at the time of the calculation, and then actually do the calculation as any other code of your program.

Comment: "and then actually do the calculation as any other code of your program."  Well, isn't the object /exe file aleady created by then? A compiler can only work on source files, not object files, right?

Comment: Well, yes, what I meant is that what the compiler does is just to produce the code that will realize the sum with the two variables and then store it in the memory address of `c`. So the compiler itself won't perform the sum, but emit the instructions that will perform it.

Answer (score 0):

`int c = a + b;`

In this case, processing this statement is probably best thought of as a two-step process.

1) Parse the statement to figure out what it means (add A and B together)

2) Perform the actual math.

#1 is difficult, #2 is easy.  #1 is slow, #2 is fast.  #1 is an algorithm you learn in college level programming, #2 is just an `add` processor instruction.

Generally, #1 is done at **compile time** (by your compiler, like `gcc` or `javac`), and #2 is done at **run time** (by the machine code in your `.exe`).

If the values of `a` and `b` come from user input, that doesn't really change things.